# Next.js setting up GraphQL .eslintrc

Tags: next.js, graphql, eslint

When I build the project, my project won't let me pass:

```
Type error: Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

  12 |  const items = products({
  13 |      where: {
> 14 |          slugIn: productSlug,
     |          ^
  15 |      },
  16 |  }).nodes
```

I know is a ESLint on GraphQL, how do I setup my ESLint to let it pass this part?

My `.eslintrc`:

```
{
    "extends": ["plugin:storybook/recommended", "next", "next/core-web-vitals", "eslint:recommended"],
    "globals": {
        "React": "readonly",
        "JSX": "readonly"
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-vars": [
            1,
            {
                "args": "after-used",
                "argsIgnorePattern": "^_",
                "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    "overrides": [{
        "files": ["*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mjs|cjs)"],
        "rules": {
            "storybook/hierarchy-separator": "error"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: That's not ESLint, it's a _type_ error. You don't need to change configuration, you need to _fix the code_.

Comment: Where are you importing the `products` function from? That is where the type error is coming from. This is likely an issue with the code or types or maybe the configuration of  "products".

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are correct mate, i though it was my eslint.

Comment: @LoganAnderson yeah it was, it was giving me a option but i ignore it somehow.

Comment: thanks guys really greatful for you guys time to look at my code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry not a eslint problem, is code error.

looks like productSlug is a union type between string | string[] , slugIn takes an array of strings i.e string[]. To get passed the typing error,  you could replace line 14 with something like this slugIn: Array.isArray(productSlug) ? productSlug : [productSlug]

change

```
const items = products({
  where: {
    slugIn: productSlug,
 },
}).nodes
```

to

```
const items = products({
    where: {
        slugIn: Array.isArray(productSlug) ? productSlug : [productSlug],
    },
}).nodes
```